# Select VISITID based on values from 2 different hit level data Bigquery

Tags: select, google-bigquery

I have a FULLVISITORID in my table with 2 different visitid.

Each visitid has multiple hits. I want to select the visitid where one hits.page.pagepath = 'somepage' 
and another hits.eventInfo.eventCategory = 'some event'. Both the conditions should be happening for the same visitid.

For Example:

Select * from `my_table` where FullVisitorid = '1'

```
FullVisitorid    Visitid   ........... hits.page.pagepath .....hits.event.eventCategory
    1              123                       A                       abc
                                             B                       cde 
                                             c                       efg
    1              147                      somePage                 ggg
                                             D                       fff
                                             E                       SomeEvent
```

I want the result to be VistiID = 147 becuase the visitid has both pagepath = 'somepage' and eventcategory = 'someevent'

Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using CTEs, you can use simple join logic to get your results.

```
with unnested as (
-- Get the fields you care about
  select FullVisitorid, Visitid, h.page.pagepath, h.event.eventCategory
  from `dataset.table`
  left join unnest(hits) h
),
somepage as (
-- Get somepage hit Visitids
  select FullVisitorid, Visitid
  from unnested
  where pagepath = 'somepage'
  group by 1,2
),
someevent as (
-- Get someevent hit Visitids
  select FulVisitorid, Visitid
  from unnested
  where eventCategory = 'someevent'
  group by 1,2
),
joined as (
-- Join the CTEs to get common Visitids
  select FulVisitorid, Visitid
  from somepage
  inner join someevent using(FullVisitorid, Visitid)
)
select * from joined
```

Comment: Thanks for your help! but I am getting error "Unrecognized Name: Pagepath" for somepage.

Comment: try lower-case `pagepath`.  I tried to keep the same capitalization as your example.

Comment: speaking of capitalization, I used lowercase `somepage` and `someevent` as in your criteria, although your sample data has `somePage` and `SomeEvent`.  please adjust accordingly